# C# Insert Record into Database table

Tags: c#, database

I have a database that contains a Customer table with the following columns : CustID, CustName, ICNumber, ContactNumber and Address. It is a service-based database.

```
string localdb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(localdb);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(CustID,CustName,ICNumber,ContactNumber,Address)values(@CustID,@CustName,@ICNumber,@ContactNumber,@Address)", con);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", txtCustID.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txtCustName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNumber", txtICNum.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
```

The code compiles and runs. The problem I am having is that the record is not added into the table after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is called.

Why is the record not showing up in the database table?

Comment: What value does ExecuteNonQuery return? Also, you should wrap your SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks.

Comment: Your code appears correct so this is most likely a database issue. Is your primary key for the table CustID? If it is you cannot enter it like you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you using a local database file?  If so, are you certain you're looking in the right file?  Your project config may be making a _copy_ of the local DB file and inserting into _that_.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the quotes `"` on the insert command. It is nice to use `try/catch` to avoid problems with your insert, for sample:

```
string localdb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(localdb))


    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(CustID, CustName, ICNumber, ContactNumber, Address) VALUES (@CustID, @CustName, @ICNumber, @ContactNumber, @Address)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", txtCustID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", txtCustName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICNumber", txtICNum.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    // some errors 
}
finally 
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
       con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why not use an  `using` statement?

Comment: Yes, could be `using` statement, but what happen if the database server is out?